# XSLT function format_number does not work for 0 with format for leading zeroes

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I would like to format a number in XSLT to have a 4 digit number with leading zeroes.

E.g.

```
1234 -> 1234
12   -> 0012
1    -> 0001
0    -> 0000
```

Therefor I use the function `format-number` as follows:

```
format-number(somevalue, '0000')
```

This works fine for everything except for 0 as *somevalue*. Here I get 0 as a result instead of 0000.

Comment: How exactly are you outputting the result?

Comment: Which version of which XSLT 2.0 processor do you use?

Comment: Not only version ... which XSLT processor? format-number(.,'0000') using XSLT and most all processors returns '0000' ... tested with Xalan and Saxon 6 (1.0) and Saxon HE/PE/EE (2.0)

Comment: I am using Saxon 9 HE for XSLT and then pipe the Result through FOP 1.1 to generate PDF.

Comment: I am outputting the result like this:                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(format-number(werte/@typ, '0000'), ' =&#160;')"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
               </xsl:choose>
              </fo:block>
             </fo:table-cell>

Comment: Which specific version of Saxon 9? It could be this bug here: https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/1190

Answer (score 0):

I have a code snippet and a template to add leading zeros.
Maybe it helps you:

```
<IDTNR>
 <xsl:call-template name="checkAndConvertNumeric">
     <xsl:with-param name="numValue" select="somevalue"/>
     <xsl:with-param name="numFormat" select="'0000'"/>
   </xsl:call-template>
</IDTNR>

<xsl:template name="checkAndConvertNumeric">
    <xsl:param name="numValue" />
    <xsl:param name="numFormat" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="normalize-space(number($numValue)) = 'NaN'">
            <xsl:value-of select="$numValue" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="string(format-number($numValue,$numFormat))" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

In the line

```
<xsl:with-param name="numFormat" select="'0000'"/>
```

you specify how many zeros you need.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the problem. I the problem is a wrong check for number like the following.

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="not(number(somevalue))">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(somevalue, ' =&#160;')"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(format-number(somevalue, '0000'), ' =&#160;')"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

number(0) gets 0 and not(0) is true. Therefore 0 is nt formatted.

I changed the number check like recommanded in the post by Peter and now it works perfectly fine.